# Error "objects of type Module are not callable" in julia

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

Julia gives MethodError: objects of type Module are not callable in the third line of this snippet:

```
function request(client::DiscordClient, method_name, url; args...)
    name = Symbol(method_name)
    Requests.json(getfield(Requests, name)(joinurl(client.baseurl, url); 
        headers = headers(client, name == :get), args...))
end
```

I'm new to Julia so there might be a better alternative to what I'm doing and I might not know about it. I appreciate all help!

Comment: Try to post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But as the error message suggests, somewhere in there you have a module which you are trying to call as a function, e.g. with ().

Comment: Yes but where? I don't understand where it is

Comment: Check out the content of `name` in `getfield(Requests, name)(...)` with `@show`. Here is a minimal example that will throw out that error. `getfield(Requests, :Requests)()`